# Not getting question Model's values in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I have created two Models Question and User Model and these are linked to each other using one to many relation as:

**Question Model**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function questions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
}
```

And my **controller code is:**

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::all();
    return view('home', compact('user'));
}
```

So, i'm trying to get question title and I have written this **code in blade:**

```
 @foreach($user as $user)
     {{ dd($user->questions->questions_title) }}
 @endforeach
```

But getting error undefined index **questions_title**, but if only write this `{{ dd($user->questions) }}` it gave me all questions, so how to fix it.

> **I have also tried `{{ dd($user->questions['questions_title']) }}` but not fixed.**

Comment: `$user->questions` is a collection. Loop over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to loop over your `questions` relationship to see your question:

```
@foreach($user as $u)
   @foreach($u->questions as $question)
       {{ dd($question->questions_title) }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Note:** I changed `$user` to `$u`

Comment: Bro great thanks I will accept it as soon as I will able to accept it again really thanks...❤❤❤

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you are not **eager loading** your `questions` relationships. Change your code to the following:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::with('questions')->get();
    return view('home', compact('user'));
}
```

Using the `with()` method will load all specified relationship with the eloquent query. After this, you will need to loop through the `questions` collection using the `->each()` collection method.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @foreach($user->question as $question)
        {{ $question->question_title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Bro tried but getting undefined index **question_title** again

Comment: Is it called `question_title` or `title` in your DB?

Answer (score 0):

No need for two `foreach` loops we can simply use one like below:

```php
@foreach ($user->questions as $question)
    {{ dd($question->questions_title) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Look at the controller code. He has a listing of users: `$user = User::all();`